# C - Two structs created in the same way, but with different values, why?

Tags: c

So, basically the code at the end of this post is my first try to implement some parallels queues.

I created the structures "fila1" and "fila2" using the same function createBase() which allocates memory space with "malloc".

Both structures were created in the same way and seems to be created correctly. However, the function prints "hellou" , but doesn't print "hi", both should be printed.

Tried to debug, and realized  when my program enters inside the "while" loop, the second "fila2" changes its memory address, also its child's value, they no longer point to "NULL". I don't understand why.  "fila1" still works as it should.

Just to illustrate, **before while loop** (working fine!):
[image]

**After** the program go past the while loop line (oh no!):
[image]

Oh, almost forgot, here is the code.
I used as input command = "a".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct Member {
        struct Member *next;
};


struct Base{
        struct Member *begin, *end;
};

//Funcoes
struct Base* createBase(){
        struct Base *new;
        new =  (struct Base*)malloc(sizeof(struct Base));
        if (new != NULL) { 
                new->begin = NULL;
                new->end = NULL; 
        }
        return new;
};


int main(void) {
        char command[1];
        struct Base *fila1, *fila2;
        struct Base *createBase();
        
        fila1 = createBase();
        fila2 = createBase();
        while(scanf("%s", &command) != EOF) {
                if (fila1->begin == NULL) {
                        printf("hellou");
                }
                if (fila2->begin == NULL) {
                        printf("hi");
                }

        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char command[1];` is most likely not big enough to hold your command.

Comment: You certainly meant `struct Member {`, no `struct Membro {`, right?

Comment: could it be the missing = in the file2->begin = NULL ? that should be ==

Comment: yes @CiaPan! struct Member, haha sorry. Already edited

Comment: What is the intention of this line `struct Base *createBase();` in main?

Comment: @MarcellJuhász oh! my bad, already fixed in the code.  Still doesn't work =((

Comment: @zois, not sure, I always try to declare the functions at the top of the main as an habit, dont know if it is really needed hahaha

Comment: You are not initializing any of the data allocated. None of the code shown writes to the structs. But it reads from the struct (e.g. `if (fila1->begin == NULL)`) which is undefined behavior (uninitialized variable).

Comment: @MortenJensen, doesn't `createBase()` initialize the `begin` member?

Comment: `scanf()` overflows `command` if the input is too long. Though that would be more likely to just cause a  segfault. In any case, the `scanf()` doesn't do anything here, so you might as well remove it as part of isolating the problem.

Comment: You can check what `scanf` returns each time. Have you verified that the loop is even executed two times?

Comment: @ilkkachu yes it totally does. I don't know how I missed that! Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @tkausl and @ilkkachu commented before, the command array is too small to contain the command itself. Even if your commands are only 1 character long (you say that you entered as command "a"), remember that the buffer will contain at least two bytes: one for the command character itself ('a') and another one for the '\0' (a char with value 0) terminating the string.

Probably scanf is storing 'a' at command[0] and trying to store the terminating '\0' at command[1] which doesn't exist (because command contains only 1 byte). This '\0' is probably overflowing command and overwriting the last byte of fila2 (note that it changes from 0xd0 to 0x00, which is exactly the value of '\0').

You should add one byte to command to accomodate the '\0' (so making it "at least" char command[2]) although I would recommend using more secure user input methods, such as fgets (which requires you to indicate the buffer size and thus would never overflow).

Comment: Just made a small edit because I had not read the exact value for command you had used.

Answer (score 1):

The first condition `fila1->begin == NULL` tests whether the `begin` membes is `NULL` – and it is, hence the printout appears.

The second one `fila2->begin = NULL` *assigns* `NULL` to the `begin` member, and then the result of this assignment is converted into integer, as required by `if()`. The integer result of the conversion is zero, which means 'false', and so the second printout does not take place.

Comment: In fact, it was a typo. Srry, already fixed, but still doesn't work =(